# HTML Entities Converting Very Strangely

Tags: php, html, string, model-view-controller, smarty

I am working on a project that involves modifying some existing code and there is a behavior going on that makes absolutely no sense to me.  I am hoping somebody has seen something similar and thus can provide some insight as to where the problem is originating from.

The best short example I can give is the following:

```
A user enters "This & that" into a textarea on an input form and when saved 
once it becomes: "This &amp;amp; that", when it is saved again it becomes:  
"This &amp;amp;amp;amp; that", save it again and you get: 
"This &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp; that".
```

Obviously the problem continues to get worse with each save.  The data actually stored in the DB (MySQL) is the text displayed above, there are no filters on the front-end to convert characters/entities.  Obviously if they were being stored properly it would be very easy to slap a call to htmlspecialchars_decode() but that isn't an option yet...

Are there some front-end checks I can be doing to see where the symbols are being mangled? I am looking at the controller that processes the data and it's using a rest event to do so but no where do I see anything that would even try to convert the HTML entities, let alone something that would incorrectly convert them.

As I said in the intro, I hope somebody may have seen this before and can help pinpoint where it might be happening.  This is built using PHP (Protean, MVC framework), Propel, patforms/smarty are in play, MySQL (via PDO) on the backend, jQuery for most JS-related stuff.

Comment: How exactly are you are storing the data and repopulating it in the text input? Does this actually have something to do with Smarty or is that tag meaningless to the question?

Comment: Data is stored using a rest event (stores post data) then smarty is just outputting what is in DB.  It's definitely a problem that is happening when the data gets saved because the garbage encoding is in the DB.

Comment: Strangely if I output what the form handler is working with, "This & that." becomes "This &amp; that." which is great, yet the DB shows "This &amp;amp; that." --> Does it sound like this is happening at the DB level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question here but it was in fact a bi-product of a set method buried in the framework that was causing the double encoding.  I changed the data flow a bit and now everything is being stored properly and I can now just throw a htmlspecialchars_decode() around the output and life is good.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone!

-- N

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being `htmlentities()` too many times. This is a common, noobish mistake that usually involves urlencoding your data before sending to the database, and encoding it again upon retrieval. Once (on output) is enough. You should never encode it going in.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I get for typing too fast =P

Comment: I agree, encoding before it goes in is highly unnecessary and leads to problems like these.  I can guarantee that this isn't being decoded on output, so the problem is something bigger.  I was hoping that someone who has used this combination of frameworks/etc had seen this before, perhaps something native to Propel PDO.  I am still digging, hope to have solution shortly.